# QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent get position will not work

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to make an application with a QGraphicsView in it. I tried to get the position of a mouse when the mouse was pressed with QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent, but it doesn't seem to work. The entire function is never called when I press the mouse.

I would like to make an application that can load an image into the QGraphicsView and then when you press the mouse button, it should add a small circle.

This is my code:

dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView = new GraphicsView();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

graphicsview.h:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSVIEW_H
#define GRAPHICSVIEW_H
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    GraphicsView();
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;

private:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
};

#endif // GRAPHICSVIEW_H
```

graphicsview.cpp:

```
#include "graphicsview.h"

GraphicsView::GraphicsView()
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    this->setScene(scene);
}

void GraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        qDebug() << "The left button was pressed!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ...: Enable mouse tracking on the `QGraphicsView`? Connect signals correct? Find the memory leak in the function you posted (Hint: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addEllipse)?

Comment: As additional questsion: How is your `scene` invoking the function `Dialog::mousePressEvent`?

Comment: @Zaiborg I just edited my post and included all the code from the dialog class

Comment: Not an answer, but you'll probably want `event->scenePos()` from the way you used the position in your code. That is, `x = int(event->scenePos().x());` and same with `y`.

Comment: @MadManiac yes I went back and forth a few times, but using scenePos didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Since I can't find much Qt documentation with examples on `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`, I'm not entirely sure how Qt wants that class to work. But regardless, for a solution that will work, you can implement your custom `GraphicsView` class which inherits `QGraphicsView`, and override `mousePressEvent` in that class. That will work for sure, since I've done it myself.

Comment: In fact, I think you're supposed to reimplement this by inheriting `QGraphicsScene`. In the documentation for [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html), its protected `mousePressEvent` is `virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)` (ie. the input variable's type is `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` instead of the usual `QMouseEvent` like in most classes), meaning that's how mouse events of graphics scenes are supposed to be implemented.

Since your class inherits `QDialog`, it's probably the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @MadManiac okay so I should make a new class for the QGraphicsScene and override QMouseEvent? Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: @MadManiac I updated my source code in the question but it still isn't working. Would you mind looking at it or sharing how you implemented the QMouseEvent into your custom QGraphicsView? Thanks!

Comment: @JustProgrammingQuestions I doubt this is supposed to make much of a difference, but one different thing I did was go directly to the ui and promote my QGraphicsView to a GraphicsView (my custom class). Beyond that, I'm not sure I see too many differences between what you did and I did, and my implementation was more towards an Adobe Illustrator-type project than a Photoshop-type one. I'll try to test your code though.

Comment: Btw, how does your mainWindow open your dialog? Do you just open it by calling the dialog directly?

Comment: Okay. I figured this out. I'd message you if I knew how since this is getting hefty for a comment section. But I'll respond with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

Just change `GraphicsView::GraphicsView()` to:

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QWidget *parent=nullptr) : QGraphicsView(parent) {}
```

and change `ui->graphicsView = new GraphicsView();` to

```
QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
verticalLayout->addWidget(new GraphicsView(this));
```

This will make the graphics view a parent of the dialog. Make sure that your dialog doesn't have anything in it when you add the code above. Alternatively, you can add a vertical layout to the dialog in your dialog.ui file and do

```
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(new GraphicsView(this));
```

I believe that solves your problem. Respond if you still have any issues.

Make sure you always have a parent parameter. Without it, you're not telling your program where it's supposed to add your widget.

Comment: thank you so much, I'll try this out